Implement Multi-browse Carousel of Material 3 in Jetpack Compose with round corners of all layouts
I had the challenge of round corners of all Multi-browse carousel layouts(large, medium, and small)
and couldn't find the correct answer. I hope to help you with this code.

   val items = listOf(
                 LocalHiPixiIconPalette.current.icHiPixiPlus,
                 LocalHiPixiIconPalette.current.icHiPixiSearch,
                 LocalHiPixiIconPalette.current.icHiPixiError,
                 LocalHiPixiIconPalette.current.icHiPixiArrowDown
              )
            HorizontalMultiBrowseCarousel(
                state = rememberCarouselState { items.count() },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(412.dp)
                    .height(221.dp),
                preferredItemWidth = 186.dp,
                itemSpacing = 8.dp,
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp)
            ) { i ->
                val item = items[i]
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.maskClip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                ) {
                    Image(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillParentMaxWidth()
                            .height(205.dp)
                            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer),
                        painter = painterResource(id = item),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                    )
                }
            }

